# 3D plot in python, space between x-ticks and the label

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following picture. How do I create distance between the **x-axis** numbering and the **label**?

[image]

The plot is created following the steps.

The structure of the code is more or less like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d; 


ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
               cmap='viridis')
ax.set_title('surface');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a value of your choice to the `labelpad` argument as following. The same can be done for y and z axis labels as well.

```
ax.set_xlabel('xxxxxxxxx', labelpad=10)
```